# Regex for a website in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Hey guys can you help me out? Right now, I have a code like this :

```
<script>
var ref = document.referrer; 
if (ref.search(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?website\.com(\/|$)/i))
{ 
    alert("**...***");
    window.location.href = "http://www.website.com";

}
</script>
```

It does track referrals from website.com but not from www.website.com thats why the code keeps on going again and again.

Can you help me out and teach me how to add a "www." regex?

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search): The `search` method returns

> The index of the first match between the regular expression and the given string; if not found, -1.

You are testing true or false, but if the index is 0, it is equivalent to false.

Test for `-1` value.

```js
var ref = "http://www.website.com"; 
if (ref.search(/^https?:\/\/([^\/]+\.)?website\.com\/?$/i) !== -1 ) { 
    //                                             here ___^^^^^^
    console.log('Match');
} else {
    console.log('No match');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there are tools like [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) where you can check and test regexes online, also there are lots of docs there and in its equivalent's websites.

I'd try something like: `ref.search(/^https?:\/\/([^\.]+\.)?website\.com(\/.*|$)?/i)`

or `ref.toLowerCase.indexOf('http://www.website.com') === 0` to check whether it certainly started like that (or not)...

Answer (score 0):

try this

> (http(s)?://)?([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?

will match

```
www.google.co
www.google.com
google.com
google.co.in
googgle.Net
www.google.com
http://www.google.com
https//gogle.com
```

Comment: What if I only want to make a regex for a certain website? For example, minifyme.com

Comment: if you want to match `mimifyme.com` only then replace the regex with that text (mimifyme.com).